Encountering 404 Error Despite Correct Path and File Existence, Website Still Not Working
when I'm trying to navigate to the specified page from another page, I encounter a 404 error, despite the existence of the file and folder.
<a href="inwekpuhien/inwekpuhien.html" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: default;">
   <img src="https://github.com/Syrinca/Syrinca.github.io/assets/165695271/eb958813-b3ae-4d71-8508-90a6000dff41" alt="" style="float: left; height: 190px; width: 20px;">
</a>

Catalog
I have checked for any errors in the path and file names, but the website still does not work.

Try setting the href in your  tag to ./inwekpuhien/inwekpuhien.html. If that doesn't work, then try changing the file name of the html document to index.html and make the href in your anchor tag ./inwekpuhien. It would be useful if you could show us your file structure and a bit more context to hat is going on in the webpage.
Hope this helps!

Thank you so much, ./inwekpuhien/index.html worked!
